# Как очистить память после exec в QSqlQuery

Tags: c++, qt

Не получается очистить память после запроса `exec`.
Читал на форуме что нужно закрыть соединение с БД,но и это не помогает.

```
QSqlQuery *SelQuery = new QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase::database("RDB"));
SelQuery->exec(filterQuerystr);
while (SelQuery->next())
    ui->CB_Device->addItem(SelQuery->value("Type").toString());

SelQuery->clear();
delete SelQuery;
```

После окончания работы этого фрагмента кода,память не освобождается даже после:

```
QSqlDatabase *db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::database("RDB"));
db->close();
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("RDB");
delete db;
```

Comment: Кст, а зачем в куче выделять память? Можно и на стеке создавать QSqlQuery, а оно после выхода из области само удалится

Comment: а как вы узнали, что память не освобождается?

Comment: еще такой момент. вашей непонятной задачи напрямую не касается, но  QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("RDB"); не будет работать в обалсти объявления QSqlDatabase *db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::database("RDB")); в отладчике это будет варнингом в стиле "database is in use"